# Fail to initiate page through javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following code to open and init new window:

```
    var self = this;

    self.editorWindow = window.open("about:blank", "Edit_image");       

    //self.editorWindow.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {

        $("body", self.editorWindow.document).append($.tmpl('Editor',{ name : img.name, albumName : FPP.Aggregator.Data[img.serviceId][img.albumId].name })).addClass("edit-page");

        var host = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host;

        // Load jQuery into new window
        var head = self.editorWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = self.editorWindow.document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = host + '/JS/Res/jquery.min.js';
        head.appendChild(script);

        // Load jQuery-ui into new window
        head = self.editorWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        script = self.editorWindow.document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = host + '/JS/Res/jquery-ui.min.js';
        head.appendChild(script);

        // Load jQuery-ui css into new window
        var link = self.editorWindow.document.createElement("link");
        link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        link.setAttribute("href", host + "/Design/Default/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css");
        head.appendChild(link);

        // Load stylesheets
        link = self.editorWindow.document.createElement("link");
        link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        link.setAttribute("href", host + "/Design/720/style.css");
        head.appendChild(link);

        // other things ...
    }, 400);
```

At first I did it like so:

```
    var self = this;

    self.editorWindow = window.open("about:blank", "Edit_image");       

    // Init stuff
```

but that didn't work in FF (in witch I was developing), so I made this

```
    var self = this;

    self.editorWindow = window.open("about:blank", "Edit_image");       

    self.editorWindow.onload = function () {
         // Init stuff
    }
```

But it wasn't working in Chrome, so the I have came up with the first code example. And it doesn't work in IE. The window is opened but is not initialized. I don't know why and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: No, it's all local. FF and Chrome would have also given me an error about this.

Comment: It's on my computer, under localhost. I'm opening the window from the code that in that domain and all loaded files are in this domain also.

Comment: You should really make a jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem.